# iOS11 SearchController in NavigationBar with Scope Buttons

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

[image]

In iOS 11 you can put a UISearchController in the NavigationBar with a few lines of code.

I set up everything in the ViewController.swift.

```
func setupNavBar() {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = wordViewController
    searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["French", "English"]
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = wordViewController

    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    // Make searchbar persistent
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}
```

In my delegate, the search fires and filters properly.  However, if I click either of the scope buttons, they simply disappear.  This delegate method is never called. (filter by scope is not actually implemented yet)

```
extension WordViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {

    if let searchText = searchBar.text {
        print("Scoped changed: \(searchText)")
        filteredWordList = wordList.filter({$0.contains(searchText)})
    }
  }
}
```

Full source is on Github:

https://github.com/melling/ios_topics/tree/master/NavBarSearch
https://github.com/melling/ios_topics/tree/master/NavBarSearch/NavBarSearch

Comment: Did you file a bug report with Apple?

Comment: yes, with source

Comment: You've misidentified what's happening. The scope bar buttons are not disappearing; the entire search controller interface is being dismissed. Let me know if you'd like to see an example with scope buttons in the navigation bar. In general, however, I have the sense that Apple would like you to use a segmented control in the results table view instead (and I can show you an example of that too if you like).

Comment: @matt Would you be able to show an example of setting up scope buttons with a nav bar?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this code within setupNavBar():

```
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

Comment: This somewhat worked. It then caused the problem of no longer being able to click on the background to dismiss the focus on the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use Artem's solution,

```
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
```

but I then ran into the problem of no longer being able to click on the background to dismiss the focus on the search bar.

To resolve this, I created my own dimmer uiview (screen size, background color of black with 25% opacity), and added that to the view of the currently presented screen, and listened for a tap. When the user taps it, I fade it out and set

```
searchController.active = false
```

Comment: can you post an example of your implementation for this?

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController, you need to add this line

`self.definesPresentationContext = YES;`

This tells the UISearchController the presentation context it needs to use, which is defined by your ViewController.

Check this link for more details: http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/228